# Timepicker - disable all time slots before the current server time

Tags: php

I created a drop-down list of time in which I show all the times in 15-minute gaps.

I want to disable all the time slots that are before the current server time.

```
<?php
// print date('H:i');
//$var="abc";
//$var = date('H:i');
 $time = date('G:i');
 echo $time;
    $start = "00:00"; 
    $end = "23:45";

    $tStart = strtotime($start);
    $tEnd = strtotime($end);
    $tNow = $tStart;
    echo '<select name="schedule_time">';
    //if($tt >= 12 && $tt <= 14){$dis = ' disabled';}else{$dis = ''}echo '<option value="wr"'.$dis.'>Washington Redskins</option>';
    while($tNow <= $tEnd)
    {
        //if($time < $start){$tNow = 'disabled';}else{$tNow = '';} echo '<option value="'.date("H:i",$tNow).'">'.date("H:i",$tNow).'</option>';
        echo '<option value="'.date("H:i",$tNow).'" disabled>'.date("H:i",$tNow).'</option>';
        $tNow = strtotime('+15 minutes',$tNow);
    }
    echo '</select>';


?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to show only `future` time Dropdown

Loop `value $tNow` is `smaller` than `current time strtotime(date('G:i'))` means you need to `disable` like this .

```
<?php

 $time = date('G:i');
 echo $time;
    $start = "00:00"; 
    $end = "23:45";
    $tStart = strtotime($start);
    $tEnd = strtotime($end);
    $tNow = $tStart;
    echo '<select name="schedule_time">';
    while($tNow <= $tEnd)
    {

        if($tNow <= strtotime(date('G:i'))){ $prop ='disabled';  }else{ $prop='';  }
        echo '<option value="'.date("H:i",$tNow).'" '.$prop.'>'.date("H:i",$tNow).'</option>';
        $tNow = strtotime('+15 minutes',$tNow);
    }
    echo '</select>';

?>
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer.But there is also one bug in these code,if i select tomorrow date than  the time which are before the server time also disabled.I want to show all time if i select tomorrow or any date.I used the bootstrap datepicker.

Answer (score 0):

You should compare the times with the server time and in case it is smaller disable the option. It would look something like this:

```
<?php
     $time = date('G:i');
     $start = "00:00"; 
     $end = "23:45";

     $serverTime = strtotime($time);
     $tStart = strtotime($start);
     $tEnd = strtotime($end);
     $tNow = $tStart;
     echo '<select name="schedule_time">';
     while($tNow <= $tEnd)
     {
        if($tNow < $serverTime) { $disable = 'disabled'; } else { $disable = ''; }
        echo '<option value="'.date("H:i",$tNow).' " '.$disable.'>'.date("H:i",$tNow).'</option>';
        $tNow = strtotime('+15 minutes',$tNow);
     }
     echo '</select>';

?>
```